# Most RESTFUL API functions cannot be unit-tested

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, tdd

```
postAdmin(req, res, cb) {
    const admin = await Admin.findOne({ req.body.username });

    if (!admin) {
        error("Admin doesn't exist");
    } //split here? adminValidationDAO();

    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if(!isMatch){
        error("Wrong password");
    } //split here? passwordValidationDAO();
    const email = new Email ({
        text: req.body.text,
        title: req.body.title,
    });
    const response = await email.save();
    //split here? saveResponseDAO()?
}
```

> Unit testing is the practice of testing small pieces of code,
>   typically individual functions, alone and isolated. If your test uses
>   some **external resource, like the network or a database, it’s not a
>   unit test.**

I was thinking of testing the code I have above, but I realized after doing some research about unit testing that what I thought was unit testing was integration testing. Testing the whole chunk of code inside postAdmin would be integration testing. Then I was wondering if I could divide the code inside postAdmin into three chunks and make them unit testable, but here are the following issues:

The first one makes a database call with findOne().

The second one relies on a library, isn't that an external resource?

The third one makes a database call with save().

So would you agree that there's nothing that can be unit tested?

Comment: You can unit test most of this. Just mock, stub, or otherwise alter all the external stuff, so you don't rely on those and then check if the rest of the logic is correct.

Comment: Should I separate the functions into three as I indicated above in the comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So would you agree that there's nothing that can be unit tested?

No: I see logic and branching, and the computation of new values.  So you have code here that can be tested in isolation.  But you might need to change other parts of your design to make this happen.

That's an important part of TDD - replacing designs that are difficult to test with designs that are easier to test.

Here, you have three functions (that are each challenging to test)

```
admin = f(req.body.username)
isMatch = g(password, user.password)
response = h(req.body.text, req.body.title)
```

... and then a bunch of logic that *doesn't care* how these three functions are implemented, just what values are returned.  So you can test everything else using whatever substitutes for those three elements you like.

```
postAdmin(req, res, cb, f, g, h) {
    const admin = f({ req.body.username });

    if (!admin) {
        error("Admin doesn't exist");
    } //split here? adminValidationDAO();

    const isMatch = await g(password, user.password);

    if(!isMatch){
        error("Wrong password");
    } //split here? passwordValidationDAO();

    const email = new Email ({
        text: req.body.text,
        title: req.body.title,
    });

    const response = h({
        text: req.body.text,
        title: req.body.title,
    });

    //split here? saveResponseDAO()?
}
```

Once you have this idea, you can experiment with different designs to manage the dependencies.

Again, because the logic is decoupled from the parts that are hard to test, you can put the logic under the microscope and ensure that everything works... even when faced with responses that are difficult to reproduce when using the "real" implementations of these dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

You definitely want to test the edge cases such as the errors thrown when queries fail or return null. You should try using a coverage tool to help you identify that all the branches (pathways) are covered with your unit testing. One great and commonly used tool is [Istanbul](https://istanbul.js.org/) . By doing that you can have an idea which statements are executed by the tests (you should aim for 100%, although that's a bit impossible). You can use a mocking framework to mock the external dependencies and drive their behavior so you can focus on your function.

For example I would mock the `Admin.findOne({req.body.username });` to return null, and test that an error is thrown.

I would do the same for the `bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);` and make it return false so I can test that an error is thrown.
Doing that you will have a suite of tests allowing you to refactor the function without the fear of changing the behavior.

Comment: So you can unit tests database calls as opposed to what's was said in the quote in bold?

Comment: Should I separate the functions into three as I indicated above in the comments?

Comment: No you don't unit test the database calls, you are testing the function behavior which is in your case, throwing error when a username is not found, or the password is incorrect, or everything went well if nothing of the above happened. I think your function is really clear what its doing and I don't really believe you will add value by separating them more. If the function gets bigger then you should probably consider delegating some parts to other functions.